# Getting values of components in a frame inside a mouse press event defined in its own class

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a tic tac toe GUI that needs to be set up as follows:

1) The frame is a grid made of 2 panes, left pane with a 9 button grif that acts as the board
2) The right pane pane is divided into two more panes 1 below the other. Based on the symbol the user chooses using the radio buttons, a click on the gameboard must display either "X" or "O".

Since my mouse listener code is in a separate class I am not sure how I can get what the user clicked.

Here is my code. Please give me a nudge in the right direction to overcome this issue.

```
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
 package samples;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE;

/**
*
* @author saikrishnan.srivat
*/
public class TicTacToe extends JFrame {

/*declare the components of the window*/
JPanel iconPanel;
JPanel tictactoeBoard;
JPanel emptyPanel;
JLabel chooseLabel;
JRadioButton xButton;
JRadioButton oButton;
ButtonGroup bg;
JButton resetButton;
JButton exitButton;
JButton undoButton;
JSplitPane rightPane;
JSplitPane pane;
MouseAdapterMod mam;

public TicTacToe() {

    iconPanel = new JPanel();
    tictactoeBoard = new JPanel();
    emptyPanel = new JPanel();
    chooseLabel = new JLabel("Choose your symbol :");
    xButton = new JRadioButton("X");
    oButton = new JRadioButton("O");
    bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(xButton);
    bg.add(oButton);

    /*add the label and the radio buttons too the empty panel*/
    emptyPanel.add(chooseLabel);
    emptyPanel.add(xButton);
    emptyPanel.add(oButton);
    emptyPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    /*add the exit,undo and reset buttons to the icon panel*/
    iconPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 3, 3));
    resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    undoButton = new JButton("Undo Move");
    iconPanel.add(resetButton);
    iconPanel.add(exitButton);
    iconPanel.add(undoButton);

    /*Set layout of the tictactoe board and add the game buttons to it */
    tictactoeBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    /* Mouse adapter object that listens to the buttons in the tic tac toe board */
    mam = new MouseAdapterMod();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        JButton button = new JButton("");
        button.addMouseListener(mam);
        tictactoeBoard.add(button);     
    }
    /*add the icon panel and the empty panel to the right pane*/
    rightPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, iconPanel, emptyPanel);

    pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, tictactoeBoard, rightPane);
    add(pane);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 400);
    //setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pack();
    setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
 }
}  

class MouseAdapterMod extends MouseAdapter {
/*Set 'X' or 'O' based the selected radio button- how to achieve this? */
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    //JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
    //button.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable within your MouseAdapterMod, and assign whatever you need (e.g. the GUI) to it (or a reference of a JButton) through the constructor.

You can then use that to access any information you need during runtime clicking.

**Example:**

Note: Use getter methods as you wish.

```
class MouseAdapterMod extends MouseAdapter {
/*Set 'X' or 'O' based the selected radio button- how to achieve this? */

    JRadioButton xButton;

    public MouseAdapterMod(JRadioButton xButton)
    {
        this.xButton = xButton;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
     JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();

     if(xButton.isSelected())
     button.setText("X");
     else
     button.setText("O");    
    }
}

/**
*
* @author saikrishnan.srivat
*/
public class TicTacToe extends JFrame {

/*declare the components of the window*/
JPanel iconPanel;
JPanel tictactoeBoard;
JPanel emptyPanel;
JLabel chooseLabel;
JRadioButton xButton;
JRadioButton oButton;
ButtonGroup bg;
JButton resetButton;
JButton exitButton;
JButton undoButton;
JSplitPane rightPane;
JSplitPane pane;
MouseAdapterMod mam;


public static void main(String args[])
{
    new TicTacToe();
}

public TicTacToe() {

    iconPanel = new JPanel();
    tictactoeBoard = new JPanel();
    emptyPanel = new JPanel();
    chooseLabel = new JLabel("Choose your symbol :");
    xButton = new JRadioButton("X");
    oButton = new JRadioButton("O");
    bg = new ButtonGroup();
    bg.add(xButton);
    bg.add(oButton);

    /*add the label and the radio buttons too the empty panel*/
    emptyPanel.add(chooseLabel);
    emptyPanel.add(xButton);
    emptyPanel.add(oButton);
    emptyPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    /*add the exit,undo and reset buttons to the icon panel*/
    iconPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 3, 3));
    resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
    undoButton = new JButton("Undo Move");
    iconPanel.add(resetButton);
    iconPanel.add(exitButton);
    iconPanel.add(undoButton);

    /*Set layout of the tictactoe board and add the game buttons to it */
    tictactoeBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    /* Mouse adapter object that listens to the buttons in the tic tac toe board */
    mam = new MouseAdapterMod(xButton);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        JButton button = new JButton("");
        button.addMouseListener(mam);
        tictactoeBoard.add(button);     
    }
    /*add the icon panel and the empty panel to the right pane*/
    rightPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, iconPanel, emptyPanel);

    pane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, tictactoeBoard, rightPane);
    add(pane);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 400);
    //setMaximumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 500));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    pack();
    setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use an array of JButtons combined with ActionListener.
Try out the following quick SSCCE I just wrote and see if it will give you some good ideas:
(Once you click any of the 9 buttons, the console shall write the button number)

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JButton button[] = new JButton[9];
public test()
{
    init();
    initializeAndAddButtons();
}

private void init()
{
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 3, 3));
    this.setSize(600,600);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setTitle("Test");
}

private void initializeAndAddButtons()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9;i++)
    {
        button[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf(i));
        button[i].addActionListener(this);
        add(button[i]);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    JButton tempButton = (JButton) e.getSource();
    System.out.println(tempButton.getText());
}
}

public class main
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    new test().setVisible(true);
   }
}
```